# Issue regarding Methods and Classes, Non-Static Error and more

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a simple program that will take inputs 1-11 from a user and digest them within a class and output a clean printed statement that will change based on these inputs.

Here is some of my current code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   
    mainInputMenu();   
}

private static void mainInputMenu() {
    System.out.println ( "=======================================\n"
            + "Welcome to the Ticket Counter\n"
            + "1. Approach first machine.\n"
            + "2. Approach Second machine\n"
            + "3. Exit." );

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner ( System.in );
    String ticketCounter;
    int counter = 0;

//I have a do while statement which confirms input but irrelevant

    while ( counter == 1 ) {
        machineOne ( counter );
    }
    while ( counter == 2 ) {
        machineTwo ( counter );
    }
    while ( counter == 3 ) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    }

public static void machineOne(int counter) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner ( System.in );
    String ticketInput;
    int choice = 0;

    TheMachine machineOne = new TheMachine();
    TheMachine.writeOutput();

    switch ( choice ) {
        case 1:
            machineOne.option = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            machineOne.option = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            machineOne.option = 3;

    }
}
```

This is the main program with up to only 3 options at the moment. Now going into what I don't understand... I can attempt to move through this via a method I thought may possibly work being to create sub-components of this class to do the work and print those variables within the writeOutput(). Which results in non-static method cannot be referenced from static context error like below.

```
public class TheMachine {
public static void writeOutput() {
System.out.println ( " ------------------------------------------\n");
System.out.println ( "Adults: " + getadultSum() ); //Simplified to show the issue


 public int getadultSum () {
    switch ( option ) {
        case 3:
            adultSum = adultSum + 1;
            return adultSum;
        case 4:
            adultSum = adultSum - 1;
            return adultSum;
    }
```

Or my first attempt solution which was to make a switch based on the option variable to change these different variables. Some include # of Adults, # of Children, Dollar Amount entered, etc.

```
static void writeOutput()
{
    int childTickets = 0;
    int adultTickets = 0;
    String route = "";
    int childSum = 0;
    int adultSum = 0;
    int creditSum = 0;


    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            route = "Uptown";
            break;
        case 2:
            route = "Downtown";
            break;
        case 3:
            adultSum = adultSum + 1;
                    break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

But this issue I run into with this one, I mean it works once around but every time you enter a new input the variable is reset to 0.

If anybody takes the time to read through this and can provide me with some help, bless you. I appreciate all your time and efforts.

Comment: *works once around but every time you enter a new input the variable is reset to 0* the variable is... `childTickets` and the like..? well, they will become 0 because once the method is left, its they become outside of context and purged. the next call, that variable will be populated with 0 again. perhaps all you need is using [property](http://www.baeldung.com/java-properties).

Comment: Okay, reading into it I'll see if I can figure that out. Really didn't think this would be so complicated, but I guess I make things complicated